# We're making a bike-powered USB charger and we have (almost) no idea what we're doing

Tags: usb, voltage-regulator, charger, test

So my friend and I are going to build a USB charger powered by a dynamo. Here is a diagram of what we are planning to do. I have a few questions:

1.) How do we test if the dynamo and breadboard circuit work? What is the easiest way to do it?

2.) Apparently, when I cut off the micro USB, there were 2 wires instead of 4 (red and white). In the 4 wire setup, white corresponds to data - and red is the 5V. Is it fine to treat the white wire as ground? If not, what do we do?[image]

Comment: That won't work.

Comment: @user34920 Can you say why it won't work? How would you change it so that it does work?

Answer (score 3):

It would be good to specify a little more information to assist in your design. For example what is the "power bank", and which components are you using on your breadboard.

I suggest that the difficulty you are going to have is that the dyamo isn't going to produce a constant 6V @ 2.4W. 
The voltage, frequency and current generated will be proportional to the speed of the bike wheel, likely up to a maximum of 6V for the motor being used (but it might shoot up higher!)

Most bicycle dynamos are alternating current (AC) and will therefore require a bridge rectifier to give you DC from the AC input.

There are countless DIY articles online with circuit diagrams and part suggestions, some of which include:

- [DIY Bicycle Dynamo USB Charger for Smartphones and Battery Packs](http://www.14degrees.org/diy-bicycle-dynamo-usb-charger-for-smartphones-and-battery-packs/)
- [Dynamo powered LED bike lights](http://www.instructables.com/id/Dynamo-powered-LED-bike-lights/)
- [Voltage Regulated [5v] Bicycle Dynamo Light & USB Charger](http://www.instructables.com/id/Voltage-Regulated-5-V-Bicycle-Dynamo-Light-USB/step1/Building-the-AC-to-DC-Driver-Voltage-regulator-cir/)

Most of these circuits offer no protection from over voltage or any other issues that might occur. There are a number of failure conditions you might want to consider, but if you trust your phone to look after itself then go ahead.

You might also find that some phones won't charge off this power because the current required to charge is higher than anything that you can generate from a 2.4W dyanmo.

There are many other design points to be discussed like the size of capacitors, selection of voltage regulator, cooling.

As for your cable, I'd suggest you find another. The USB standard says white is for DATA.

BTW: You can also buy phone charger systems for bikes pretty cheap, but that's no fun :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply :D I'll add some more details ASAP.